# How to remove lines on the bar chart

Tags: jquery, jqplot

How to remove lines on the bar chart. (These are appearing when add js for the line chart in jqPlot) .Not Grid lines in the chart. lines on bars.

[image]

Comment: Check if edited answer helps.

Comment: can u give the code? lines wont appear by default

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
series: {
    0: {
        targetAxisIndex: 0
    },
    1: {
        targetAxisIndex: 0
    },
    2: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1,
        type: "line"
    },
    3: {
         targetAxisIndex: 1,
         lineWidth: 0,
         pointSize: 3,
         type: "line"
    },
}
```

You can put lineWidth = 0 if you want to show points, and not line.

Edit: Sorry, that was for google chart. For jqPlot use this:

```
seriesDefaults: {    
    showLine:false
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your reply. this method is working for Line chart. but not working in barchart :( .when i put showLine:false in barchart line appears and all bars disappear. Any idea ?

Comment: Ok.. @ErangaLakmalPerera Try drawBaseline option like [this](http://pastie.org/8527605)

Comment: That method also not working.im using jsplot  version: 1.0.8 .

Comment: Ohk :( sorry. Then no idea. Will tell you if I find something.

Comment: Thanks Anamika .I will let you know if i found a solution .